# Reverse words from SCANNER using STACK and RECURSION

Tags: java, recursion, stack

Is there a way to get words from SCANNER and reverse them with both STACK and RECURSION? I need all three aspects in this program. I am able to do this with Stack alone or with Recursion alone but I have not been able to make both work together.

```
public class Reverse {
    public static String wordReverse(String[] theWords) {
        Stack <String> stacker = new Stack <String>();
        for(String wordsHold : theWords) {
            stacker.push(wordsHold);
        }
        while ( !stacker.empty() ) {
               stacker.pop();
        }
        return wordReverse(theWords);  // Cause of StackOverflowError
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner takeIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String allWords = takeIn.nextLine();
        String[] goodWords = allWords.split(" ");
        System.out.println(wordReverse(goodWords)); 
        takeIn.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, we'll start on your homework right away...

Comment: Recursion *is* a stack/unstack operation, though implicitly.

Comment: Kevin if you went to school you should know there is no school at this time. This is practice I have chosen to do on my own. Please post something useful or don't post at all.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to remember when recursing, is to define the stop condition;

```
public static String wordReverse(String[] theWords, Stack<String> stack) {
    // stop on null.
    if (theWords == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (theWords.length < 2) {
        // stop if there are fewer then two words.
        return theWords[0];
    }
    // push the first word.
    stack.push(theWords[0]);
    // copy the sub-array.
    String[] s = new String[theWords.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(theWords, 1, s, 0, theWords.length - 1);
    // recurse
    return wordReverse(s, stack) + " " + stack.pop();
}

public static String wordReverse(String[] theWords) {
    // call the recursive implementation with a new Stack.
    return wordReverse(theWords, new Stack<String>());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner takeIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String allWords = takeIn.nextLine();
    String[] goodWords = allWords.split(" ");
    System.out.println(wordReverse(goodWords));
    takeIn.close();
}
```

Works like so

```
Hello world, goodbye world
world goodbye world, Hello
```